# Open default excel data form for specific table with macro

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

Im working on a speadsheet with multiple large tables whose info is entered via spreadsheet based userforms i have created, as i am not familiar or comfortable using vba userforms, and i am trying to call entries back up in order to edit them.

The easiest way i can think of to do this is to open the default excel dataform. What i need to know is; is there any way to open this dataform for a specific table with criteria already entered?

eg. I need to edit a product table, so i already know that im editing the product table and i know the name for the product. I have a little userform, again spreadsheet based, where i select the entry type(in this case a product) and then enter the product name. What i want to do is use that info to open a dataform for the product table with the criteria field of the name already filled out so as to reduce time spent searching for the entry as these tables have hundreds of entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this simple example I take your Worksheet with the products is called "Products". There are two columns with Names in column A and IDs in column B

On the Userform I place two textboxes called

- TextBox_Productname
- TextBox_ProductID

I then added the following code to the Userform that will trigger whenever the value of the productname textbox changes and it looses focus.

```
Private Sub TextBox_Productname_Change()

    ' Clear the content of all Textboxes but the Productname
    TextBox_ProductID.Value = ""

    ' Analyse the Cells in the Worksheet called "Products"
    With Worksheets("Products")

        ' Assume in the first row are the headers so start
        ' looking at the second row and go to the final one
        For i = 2 To .UsedRange.Rows.Count

            ' check whether the value in the first column
            ' matches the value of the Textbox_Productname
            If .Cells(i, 1) = TextBox_Productname.Value Then

                ' If there is a match copy the values of all
                ' the other columns to the textboxes
                TextBox_ProductID.Value = .Cells(i, 2)
            End If

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```